# Singlespacing long captions more than one line in the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, koma-script

I tried the solution `\caption[\protect\vspace{-0.5ex}{ long caption text}]{long caption text}`, but it does nothing. I need a constant double spacing in LOF and when it comes to the long captions more than one line, it must be single spaced. Could you please help? thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}% if ToC should be on section level
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%% document setup
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\usepackage[list-entry=heading]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% <- changed


\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}%make caption label bold
\setkomafont{caption}{\bfseries}%make caption bold
\setcapindent{0pt}%removes hanging indent from captions





%----------------%-------------------------%-----------
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\addvspace#1{}
\clearpage % to force a new page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
%\doublespacing
\endgroup
\mainmatter

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test}
\caption[\protect\vspace{-0.25ex}{ llong caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text }]{1long caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text 6long caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}


\includegraphics{test2}
\caption[\protect\vspace{-0.5ex}{ llong caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text }]{1long caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text 6long caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So set the list of figures (and other TOCs) single-spaced you can add a `\singlespacing` or `\setstretch{1}` at the very beginning either immediately after the heading using `\AfterTOCHead` or immediately before reading the auxiliary file of the corresponding TOC using `\BeforeStartingTOC`, e.g.

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\singlespacing}% for the list of figures only
```

or

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\singlespacing}% for every TOC (i.e. table of contents, list of figures, list of tables)
```

To have the white line between entries to the list of figures, you can change option `beforeskip`, e.g., using

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=\baselineskip]{tocline}{figure}
```

This have to be done for all entry types that should have it. For tables copy the command and replace `figure` by `table`.

See the `tocbasic` chapter in the KOMA-Script manual for more information.

For entries to the table of contents you could also use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocbeforeskip=\baselineskip]{section,subsection}
```

See part II of the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

To put the list of figures and the list of tables into the table of contents you should also use a special KOMA-Script feature: option `listof=totoc`. To remove the chapter gap from these list you also don't need to locally redefine `\addvspace` but can use option `listof=nochaptergap`.

With these changes you do not longer need to use the optional argument of `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot,
  listof=totoc,listof=nochaptergap% <--- ADDED
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}% if ToC should be on section level
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%% document setup
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\usepackage[list-entry=heading]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}%make caption label bold
\setkomafont{caption}{\bfseries}%make caption bold
\setcapindent{0pt}%removes hanging indent from captions

\BeforeStartingTOC{\singlespacing}% <--- ADDED
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=\baselineskip]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=\baselineskip]{tocline}{table}    

%----------------%-------------------------%-----------
\begin{document}

\frontmatter% <--- ADDED (without \mainmatter wouldn't make sense)

% CHANGED:
\listoffigures
\mainmatter

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test}
\caption{llong caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}


\includegraphics{test2}
\caption{llong caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The list of figures uses `\l@figure` to do the formatting, so I added an extra `\vspace{\baselineskip}`.  This should work with any document class.

Double spacing is done by typewriters. Typesetters add extra space between lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}% if ToC should be on section level
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%% document setup
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\usepackage[list-entry=heading]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table
%\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% <- changed


\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}%make caption label bold
\setkomafont{caption}{\bfseries}%make caption bold
\setcapindent{0pt}%removes hanging indent from captions

\makeatletter
\let\oldl@figure=\l@figure
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\oldl@figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\addvspace#1{}
\clearpage % to force a new page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures}%\doublespacing
\endgroup
\mainmatter

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test}
\caption{1long caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text 6long caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}


\includegraphics{test2}
\caption[\protect\vspace{-0.5ex}{ llong caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text }]{1long caption text 2long caption text 3long caption text 4long caption text 5long caption text 6long caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it increases the vertical distance between the lines 2 times more than what I expect. Any suggestion how to fix that? again, thank you @John Kormylo

Comment: Did you lose the doublespacing?  Anyway, you can replace the \baselineskip with something smaller, like 0.5\baselineskip.